# Refund on Debit Card

Tags: debit-card, refund

Using my debit card, my brother bought me an iPhone charger at Walgreens for 40 dollars. I immediately went back to the store and returned it with my debit card and handed back the receipt. When everything was over, I handed the product back but  I absentmindedly threw the receipt out.

Will I still get my refund?  How long will it take for it to go back into my account? What happens if the return is taking too long?

My brother definitely won't be buying anything for me ever again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you physically gave the item back and the cashier processed the return correctly, there would be no reason to doubt that you will get your money back.

By regulation, the transaction may take a very long time (merchants are allowed 1 business day to settle refunds against Mastercard and 5 against Visa, then your bank is allowed 10 days to process the transaction and fund your account). However, in practice, many refunds show up much more quickly than that, and you may have the money in a few days.

It's hard to give a specific answer, because the specifics depend on how and when the merchant submits the transaction, and how and when your bank processes it. When in doubt, you can always ask (both the merchant and your bank) although you may get answers of "I don't know" or "it depends" or something generic like "up to X days."

Comment: How do I know that my cashier processed the return correctly? Sorry for my stupid questions. I just got my debit card a month ago. I'm still relatively new to these processes. Also, is the thrown out receipt any sort of security risk?

Comment: Without the receipt, I suppose you don't know. But, returns are a very normal course of business for retail operations and unless you have a strong reason to suspect that the cashier made a mistake, it's probably safe to assume they did not.

Comment: Thrown out receipts are not inherently risky. They generally do not include any personal information about you (other than what you bought). And they absolutely do not include any information that could be used to access your account (i.e. your full card number is not on your receipt).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will just have to hope for the best.